# No incorrect HTML markup but getting: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm really confused as to why I'm getting the error:

```
The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

I should mention that I don't believe the project uses `nuxt`, which lots of other similar questions have projects using `nuxt`. Having said that I know the project does use server side rendering and from `package.json` I see `"vue-server-renderer": "2.6.11"`.

What I am confused about is my component which gets rendered on this particular route literally has almost nothing in it, as shown below and still gets the error. As you can see I've removed everything in the `template` tag other than just the `p` tag.

```
<template>
  <p>123</p>
</template>

<script>
import TwoColumn from "@/components/layouts/TwoColumn";
import FeedbackForm from "@/components/inputs/FeedbackForm"
import { ALL_HOME } from "@/router/routes"
export default {
  components: {
    TwoColumn,
    FeedbackForm,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      formActive: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goTo() {
      return {
        name: ALL_HOME.name
      }
    },
    contactUs() {
      this.formActive = !this.formActive
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.highlight {
  color: #4D0099;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

What do I need to do to fix the problem? Having little knowledge in SSR, what causes errors like this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem was I had an `a` tag with in a `router-link` tag which caused the error. I forgot to clear the cache so the browser kept giving me the same error even though I only had the `p` tag in the template..once the browser cache is cleared and then removing the `router-link` tag fixed the problem.